# Tables getting dropped when running node server.js and re-seeding db. Sequelize

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, seed

I'm running into an error where when I do a get request in node to my database, I'm getting an empty array. So I look in the console log and it says it's dropping all tables if exist and then creating them but the seed file is not running. I can run "npm run seed" outside of the server and it will seed the database but it keeps dropping and not seeding when I run node server.js. I even tried putting the path to the seed inside the packages.json "start": to make both the seed and server run on start but no luck. The app was working perfectly but one of my team members accidentally pushed to the master and it messed up the app I don't know what's messed up because this was working before the git messup. I've created a new repo though now and getting same problem.

```
 //package.json
 "start": "node server.js ./seeds/seed-db.js"


    //seed-db.js
     const db = require("../models");
    const productSeeds = require("./seed-products.json");

     db.sequelize.sync({ force: true }).then(function() {
      db.Market.bulkCreate([
     {
  name: "Cotton Mill Farmers Market",
  address: "401 Rome St.",
  city: "Carrollton",
  state: "GA",
  zip: "30117"
 }
    ]).then(function(dbMarkets) {
//COTTON MILL FARMERS MARKET STOCK
   dbMarkets[0].createProduct(productSeeds.broccoli).then(function() {
  db.sequelize.close();
   });


dbMarkets[1].createProduct(productSeeds.broccoli).then(function() 
 {
  db.sequelize.close();
      });
       });
    });
```

//console

Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `MarketProduct`;
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Product`;
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Markets`;
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Markets`;
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Markets` (`id` INTEGER NOT NULL auto_increment , `name` VARCHAR(255), `address` VARCHAR(255), `city` VARCHAR(255), `state` VARCHAR(255), `zip` INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB;
Executing (default): SHOW INDEX FROM `Markets` FROM `grocerEZ_db`
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Product`;
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Product` (`id` INTEGER NOT NULL auto_increment , `name` VARCHAR(255), `category` ENUM('meat', 'fruits', 'vegetables', 'misc'), `isOrganic` TINYINT(1), PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB;
Executing (default): SHOW INDEX FROM `Product` FROM `grocerEZ_db`
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `MarketProduct`;
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `MarketProduct` (`createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt`DATETIME NOT NULL, `MarketId` INTEGER , `ProductId` INTEGER , PRIMARY KEY (`MarketId`, `ProductId`), FOREIGN KEY (`MarketId`) REFERENCES `Markets` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE, FOREIGN KEY (`ProductId`) REFERENCES `Product` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE) ENGINE=InnoDB;
Executing (default): SHOW INDEX FROM `MarketProduct` FROM `grocerEZ_db`
App listening on PORT 3000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change

```
db.sequelize.sync({ force: true }) // <-- Forces table to drop and create again
```

to

```
db.sequelize.sync({ force: false , alter : true })
```

---

> **[DOC :](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/sequelize.js~Sequelize.html#instance-method-sync)**
>
> If force is true, each Model will run DROP TABLE IF EXISTS, before it
>   tries to create its own table
>
> Alters tables to fit models. Not recommended for production use.
>   Deletes data in columns that were removed or had their type changed in
>   the model.

---

> **NOTE :**
>
> db.sequelize.sync , this should run only once , when you want to
>   create / modify the table based upon the changes you have made on
>   models , would suggest to put that in separate file and run it when it
>   is required.
>
> This is how you should run query by checking connection not by running
>   sync ,
>
> ```
> db.sequelize
> .authenticate()
> .then(() => {
>     console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
> })
> .catch(err => {
>     console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', err);
> });
> ```

Comment: I couldn't get it work. Still drops tables if exists

Comment: @walkforr , please make sure that `sync()` it not written any where else , remove it from all places , and if you want to keep that make it `sync({ force: false })` , as this is the only thing that make tables drops if exists. and also restart the server once changes are being made.

Comment: after some days of moving around my code, your solution worked. thanks so much. force: false.